# hook_node_access not working

Tags: 7, users

I am trying to use hook_node_access to change some permissions when viewing a node type.  The problem is that even when I call it in my module, it doesn't work.

```
function MyModule_node_access($node,$op,$account) {
  die("it works!");
}
```

I can 100% confirm that other hooks in the same module are working fine.  I have disabled and reenabled the module.  I have cleared all cache.  I can confirm that my test user is not uid = 1, and it does not have the "Bypass content access control" permission.  So why is hook_node_access not working for me?  Does it not work by itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

node_access is a hook like any other, so I can see no reason why it wouldn't be called if:

- your hook implementation is named correctly
- the module is activated
- the file the hook implementation is in has been included
- the 'module_implements' cache has been cleared
- the page you are viewing is calling node_access() at some point (try a `node/xxx` page for example.)

You might try executing `module_implements('node_access')` and checking if your module is included in that list.

If so, node_access is not being called.

If not, the function YourModule_node_access does not exist, or is not included.

Comment: BINGO! You said "try a node/xxx page for example.".  I was trying to view revisions (/node/XXX/revisions/XXX/view) for a particular node.  Using "/node/XXX" works!  THANK YOU! I also found there is a separate hook for revisions access which I will look into since I will need to override that as well.  THANK YOU penten!

Comment: I got the problem, I am viewing a node and module_implements('node_access') returns my module implementation, viewing a node and node.module enabled, why wouldn't that work ?

Answer (score 26):

I used `hook_node_access()` and had the same issue: It wasn't firing and driving me nuts.

What worked for me was NOT to be logged in as an admin. I went in as a different role and all worked as expected.

Answer (score 8):

From [hook_node_access](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7#comment-26879)

> The administrative account (user ID #1) always passes any access
>   check, so this hook is not called in that case. Users with the "bypass
>   node access" permission may always view and edit content through the
>   administrative interface.

Comment: as @Jonathan Jae Rosero said, you can't be admin and expect it to work out... I would say, it's missing that fact in the documentation, where they say "user ID #1" I guess they mean, 'user admin role'