# Help using hook_node_access

Tags: users

I'm trying to use [`hook_node_access`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7) in my custom module to do the following:

I have a lot of nodes (of type '*order*') with a field called *customer* (1, 2, 3, 4)  and there are users who also have a field called *customer* (1, 2, 3, 4). I need to have it so that only the user with the customer field value of '2' can view, update and delete nodes only with customer field value of '2'

Comment: Check that you are trying to access the **full node** and that the current user is not the admin user.

Comment: Also check this [related answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58219/hook-node-access-not-working).

Comment: Please refrain from asking multiple questions in one question. I've edited it out - but there's no reason why it couldn't be another question :)